# If $e_0, \dots, e_r$ is a dual basis to $x_0, \dots, x_r$, then $e_i^2=0$, $e_ie_j=-e_je_i$. How is it that $e_i^2=0$, $e_ie_j=-e_je_i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In Section 7B of Geometry of Syzygies by Eisenbud, we have the following setup:

> Let $S=k[x_0,\dots,x_r]$ and write $W=S_1$ for the space of linear forms. Let $\hat W = \mathrm{Hom}_k(W,k)$.

> Eisenbud writes that if $e_0, \dots, e_r$ is a dual basis to $x_0, \dots, x_r$, then $e_i^2=0$, $e_ie_j=-e_je_i$.

I know that $e_i: W \to k$ and $e_i : x_j \mapsto \delta_{i,j}$. Is $e_i^2$ the product $e_i\cdot e_i$? If so, then $e_i^2$ should map $x_i$ to $1^2=1$.

**How is it that $e_i^2=0$, $e_ie_j=-e_je_i$?**

Comment: Forms are skewsymmetric and so it is their dual. I have removed the tags algebraic geometry and polynomials, as I can't see how this question is related to those

Comment: @Marco What do you mean by forms are skew-symmetric?

Comment: @Marco If I take two linear forms $x_i, x_j$, we have $x_ix_j = x_jx_i$. How is this skew-symmetric?

Comment: What is the definition you have of linear form? For me is an element  of the exterior algebra, and so it is skew symmetric by definition

Comment: @user5826 At the beginning of section 7B in my copy (are there even multiple editions?) Eisenbud explicitly tells you he is considering $E = \bigwedge V$, an exterior algebra. The naming $e_i$ should convince you that you are to consider these as elements of $E$.

Comment: @Marco Eisenbud writes $W=S_1$ for the space of linear forms at the beginning of the chapter. So linear forms are the monomials $x_0, \dots, x_r$.

Comment: @BenSteffan He writes: If $e_0, \dots, e_r$ is a dual basis to $x_0, \dots, x_r$ then $e_i^2=0, $e_ie_j=-e_je_i$.

Comment: @BenSteffan Is $e_i^2$ the same as $e_i \wedge e_i$? Or is it the linear functional $e_i$ squared?

Comment: @user5826 For comment 1: yes, he does; right after setting up $V$, and $E$. For comment 2: It is $e_i \wedge e_i$.